# Post sign-up flow with Azure B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

We are using Azure B2C for sign-ups of external users.
By default, we only provide limited access on sign-up, as we need to ensure the user gets assigned to the right profiles within AD and link things up with SalesForce.

Currently, this is done manually using a report, but we want to semi-automate it, by automatically raising a support ticket, so somebody can check it out

The question is how we can detect if a new user has signed up successfully and act on that? Preferably as part of the sign-up flow, but separate event-based flow could also be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just before sending the JWT in the signup/in flow, you could do e.g.

```
<Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
        <Value>newUser</Value>
        <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
</Preconditions>
<ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="RaiseSupportTicket" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST-RaiseSupportTicket"/>
</ClaimsExchanges>
```

and then call an API.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for. Had not realised earlier this option.